# How to show rating on recent view products?

Tags: product-view

I want to show rating star on recently viewed products.
Is that possible?

```
 <?php foreach ($_products as $_item):  ?>
 <?php if($_item->getRatingSummary()){ ?>
                      <?php echo $this->getReviewsSummaryHtml($_item, 'short') ?>

                     <?php }?>
 <?php endforeach; ?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can get the rating summary by below code

```
<?php
$storeId = Mage::app()->getStore()->getId();
$summaryData = Mage::getModel('review/review_summary')
                    ->setStoreId($storeId)
                    ->load($item->getId()); //your product id
if($summaryData->getRatingSummary()):
?>
    <div class="ratings">
        <div class="rating-box">
            <div class="rating" style="width:<?php echo $summaryData->getRatingSummary(); ?>%"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
<?php endif;?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by modifying your THEME/default/reports/product_viewed.phtml template file, render the rating html with:

```
<?php
    $storeId = Mage::app()->getStore()->getId();
    $summaryData = Mage::getModel('review/review_summary')->setStoreId($storeId)->load($_item->getId());
?>

<?php if ($summaryData['rating_summary']):?>
    <div class="ratings">
    <div class="rating-box">
      <div class="rating" style="width:<?php echo $summaryData['rating_summary']; ?>%"></div>
      </div>
    </div>  
<?php endif; ?>
```